# jQuery Animate Question

Tags: jquery

I have a very basic function which I am using jQuery to slide some content either out (from left to right) or back in (from right to left). The code below works, however, what I am trying to do now is include the "+" at the end of my "overDiv", and make it so that it will always show.

To paint a more lucid picture, right now if you paste that code into your editor and include google's jQuery, you will see that clicking the "+" eliminates the "overDiv" block completely. However, what I want to do is place the "+" at the end of the "overDiv" block so that when the text 'disappears' off of the page, the + will always remain. Hopefully that makes some sense?

Thanks in advance.

```
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // when we click on the a-href id 'togglen', we move the overDiv to the left.
$('#togglen').click(function() {
    // simple animation                          
    $('#overDiv').animate({
      left: parseInt($('#overDiv').css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$('#overDiv').outerWidth() : 0
    });
  }); // 
});


</script>
<div><a href="#" id="togglen">+</a></div>
<div style="background-color:#CCC; width:180px;  position:absolute; left:0; overflow:hidden; float:left;" id="overDiv">Lorem ipsum.</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KmmbK/ I pasted your code into a jsfiddle. Looks like the '+' does always remain. Do you want the '+' inside the disappearing div? If so simply subtract the width of the '+' from the distance the div animates off screen.

Comment: This is exactly what I Was looking for. Thank you to everyone that answered. And thanks, Fresheyeball.. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `position` of sliding `div` to `relative` and `float` `left` the `div` with `+`. This way there is no hard coding of any values in the `div` with `+`

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jyzuL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like `style="position:absolute; left:190px"` to your +.

If you want the + to "stick" to the "overDiv" you can add

```
$('#togglen').animate({
        left: parseInt($('#overDiv').css('left'),10) == 0 ? 0 : $('#overDiv').outerWidth()
    });
```

before the other animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/PQxkc/

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/yVReu/

You need to also position your "+" element.

Comment: Hey Paul, is there any way to put the "+" at the 0px level once I click on the "+" ?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - Why not? It's absolutely positioned.

Comment: @meoww - Not sure I understand what you're asking. You want the "+" to slide in/out as well?

Comment: @Paul - You cannot hard code the `left(181px)` value, What if the sliding div content changes will it work?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - My answer was based on the code given (and the original element was hard coded @ 180px)